# Assembly load in roslyn

Tags: c#, roslyn

I would like to load assembly, who have my class declaration. 
I tried:

```
 var compilation = Compilation.Create("HelloTest").AddReferences(MetadataFileReference.CreateAssemblyReference("ClassLibrary6.dll")).AddSyntaxTrees(tree);
```

So I have execption: "Assembly file not found"

So how Can I add a assembly reference to be able to semantic analysis?

I tried:
MetadataFileReference.CreateAssemblyReference
and 
MetadataFileReference.CreateAssemblyReference

Answer (score 2):

`MetadataFileReference.CreateAssemblyReference` is intended for looking up assembly in the GAC by their Assembly Identity, not their path.  Try creating a `new MetadataFileReference(...)` instead, and make sure that the path can be resolved from your application's current directory.